# Metal multisampling results in darkened textures

Tags: objective-c, metal, antialiasing, multisampling

So I'm trying to implement full-screen MSAA in my Metal app. I have it working and when drawing solid-filled polygons the edges appear smooth as expected. However, my textured polygons appear dark, and get darker as I increase the number of samples, indicating that the shader might be taking only one sample of the texture per fragment and blending it with `n - 1` samples of black therefore making it darker.

However, in my app I also have textures that I render to and then draw to the screen. These textures show up perfectly fine. I can't really see a difference between the two kinds of textures that would change the behavior of multisampling.

Anyway, if anyone could maybe give me any clues as to what's going on, I would greatly appreciate it. I'm pretty stumped on this one.

EDIT:

[Here is how I am setting up all my pipeline state(s)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LT9cU.png)

[Here is how the texture pipeline state is set up specifically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfJ1v.png)

Comment: You'll need to show code. In particular, how are you setting up the render pass descriptor and render pipeline state? Are you properly resolving the multisample texture to a non-multisample texture for the actual draw to the screen?

Comment: @KenThomases added some pipeline state setup code. I know that I have proper texture resolve for my draw to the screen because my colored polygons look as they should: the right brightness and with smooth edges. Which tells me it's either a problem with my pipeline states or with the textures themselves.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. The problem was that I hadn't set my stencil draw pipeline state to be multisampled. Therefore it was only reading the value in the stencil buffer for 1 out of n samples and hence darkening the output. Works fine now.

Comment: hi can you say exactly how you did to make your  stencil draw pipeline state to be multisampled ?